# Unable to handle state 'loading' properly in react with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Hey guys just moved to redux so in react what i was doing was in componentDidMount(), i was calling api and soon as i received the data i was setting loading to false (initially loading was true) to get rid of the 'react spinner',

but after using redux now in componentDidMount() i am calling my action creater which is in another and there i am receving my data so how do i manage 'loading' here ? can i somehow pass something from action creater to my component that triggers state and set loading to false ? or is there any other to do it ? How do you all manage it ?

here is my code

Home.js

```
class home extends Component {
  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.props.verifyToken();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.categoryAction();

  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categoriesWithTheirImages: [],
      displayToggle: false,
      loading: false,
    };
  }


  renderCategory = () => {

    return this.props.allCategories.map((item) => {
      return (
        <div
          className="category_div"
          key={item._id}
          onClick={() => this.setState({ displayToggle: true })}
        >
          <img
            src={item.image}
            alt="miss-mistake"
            className="category_image_home"
          />
          <span className="category_heading_home">{item.categoryName}</span>
        </div>
      );
    });

  };

  render() {

    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <div className="sweet-loading-main">
          <FadeLoader
            css={override}
            sizeUnit={"px"}
            size={50}
            color={"#ff9d72"}
            loading={this.state.loading}
          />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      console.log(this.props.allCategories);
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          {/* <Fade left> */}
          <Header />
          <div className="main_content_homepage">
            <p className="category_select">Please select a category</p>
            <div className="category_list">{this.renderCategory()}</div>
          </div>
          {this.renderStoryActionDialog()}
          {/* </Fade> */}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  const images = [family, ring, beer, feedback, academic];
  let categoriesWithImages = state.getCategoryReducer.map((item, index) => {
    item.image = images[index];
    return item;
  });
  console.log(categoriesWithImages);
  return { allCategories: categoriesWithImages };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { verifyToken, categoryAction })(home);
```

and my action.js file

```
import { CATEGORY } from "../actionTypes";
export const categoryAction = ()=> {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/get_categories", {
      method: "GET",
    }).then(res=>res.json())
      .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        dispatch({ type: CATEGORY, payload: response });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log("Eror in adding", err));
  };
};
```

reducer file

```
import { USER, CATEGORY} from "../actionTypes";
const getCategoryReducer = (state = [], action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case CATEGORY:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }

};

export default getCategoryReducer;
```

Comment: I typically keep loading state in my redux store as well, so when you're done loading you can dispatch a `LOADED` action. Another option would be to have `loaded` in your component be based on whether the `allCategories` prop has anything in it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the loading state in your `reducer` file. At the moment, it's defined in your `Component` file. For e.g when you dispatch the action, it should update your loading state too. I would do something like this in reducer.

```
import { USER, FETCH_CATEGORY, FETCH_CATEGORY_SUCCESS, FETCH_CATEGORY_FAIL} from "../actionTypes";
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    loading: false,
    err: false,
    data: []
}
const getCategoryReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_CATEGORY:
       return Object.assign({}, state, {
            loading: true,
            data: [],
        })

      case FETCH_CATEGORY_SUCCESS
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            loading: false,
            data: action.payload,
        })

       case FETCH_CATEGORY_FAIL
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            loading: false,
            data: action.payload,
            err: true
        })

    default:
      return state;
  }

};

export default getCategoryReducer;
```

and your action file would look something like this

```
import { FETCH_CATEGORY, FETCH_CATEGORY_SUCCESS, FETCH_CATEGORY_FAIL } from "../actionTypes";
export const categoryAction = ()=> {
  //setting loading to true
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_CATEGORY });
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/get_categories", {
      method: "GET",
    }).then(res=>res.json())
      .then(response => {
         //setting loading to false
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_CATEGORY_SUCCESS, payload: response });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log("Eror in adding", err);  dispatch({ type: FETCH_CATEGORY_FAIL, payload: err }););
  };
};
```

You can then read the loading props in your `Home.js`